# Generating a large dropdown list

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm making a large form in Laravel 8 and one of the dropdown lists has to contain values from 1 to 85.

Is there a way that I can generate the list using a loop instead of having to type out the whole 85 options?

My current code is

```
    <div class="col-sm-2">
       <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('map1_id') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
          <select class="selectpicker col-sm-12 pl-0 pr-0" name="map1_id" data-style="select-with-transition" title="" data-size="40">
             @foreach($user as $users)
                <option value="{{$users->map1}}" @if (old('map_id', $users->map1)) selected="selected" @endif>{{$users->map1}}</option>
             @endforeach
         </select>
       @include('alerts.feedback', ['field' => 'map1id'])
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@for ($i = 1; $i <= 85; $i++)

@endfor
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#loops

Comment: Thanks, Michael, I had tried that a couple of times but it didn't work, I realised that I had put the twos around the wrong way.

Having gotten it to work I realised it was just too long so I changed it out to:

`<input class="form-control{{ $errors->has('map1') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="map1" id="input-map1" type="number" min="0" max="85" placeholder="{{ __('Map Number') }}" value="{{ old('map1', $user->map1) }}" required="true" aria-required="true"/>`